# Setting up amazon sns in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-sns

I need to setup amazon SNS in symfony2 . For this i tried using [mcfedr/awspushbundle](https://packagist.org/packages/mcfedr/awspushbundle) bundle with Symfony version 2.3.42 but i am unable to use it due to outdated dependencies. Now the issue is i cannot update my other bundles . So is their any other compatible bundle or process to do messaging using Amazon SNS??

Issue i got was

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - mcfedr/awspushbundle 6.5.1 requires symfony/symfony ^2.8|^3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev, 3.1.x-dev, 3.2.x-dev, v2.8.0, v2.8.0-BETA1, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v3.0.0, v3.0.0-BETA1, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.1.0, v3.1.0-BETA1, v3.1.0-RC1, v3.1.1, v3.1.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - mcfedr/awspushbundle 6.5.0 requires symfony/symfony ^2.8|^3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev, 3.1.x-dev, 3.2.x-dev, v2.8.0, v2.8.0-BETA1, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v3.0.0, v3.0.0-BETA1, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.1.0, v3.1.0-BETA1, v3.1.0-RC1, v3.1.1, v3.1.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for mcfedr/awspushbundle ^6.5 -> satisfiable by mcfedr/awspushbundle[6.5.0, 6.5.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Looks like 2.3's maintenance period [just ended](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html#schedule) (or is about to) - have you considered upgrading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully used the official package, available via composer [AWS SNS Message Validator](https://github.com/aws/aws-php-sns-message-validator). But this is just for validating SNS messages.

If you need to publish messages, try the official SDK. [AWS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php)
It is really not that hard to handle and you don't run into dependency issues.